# Looping on ranges (Modular iterations)

Tags: parametric-functions, procedural-programming, modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to make the following code modular, so that it works up till depth n, and returns an array of all possible combinations for `used{}`?

`ranges` is an nx2 array which contains the ranges for the ith loop.

```
    used = Table[0, lb]
    For[i = ranges[[1, 1]], i <= ranges[[1, 2]], i++,
     used[[1]] = i;
     For[j = ranges[[2, 1]], j <= ranges[[2, 2]], j++,
      If[FreeQ[used, j],
       used[[2]] = j;
       For[k = ranges[[3, 1]], k <= ranges[[3, 2]], k++,
        If[FreeQ[used, k],
         used[[3]] = k;
         For[l = ranges[[4, 1]], l <= ranges[[4, 2]], l++,
          If[FreeQ[used, l],
           used[[4]] = l;
           For[m = ranges[[5, 1]], m <= ranges[[5, 2]], m++,
            If[FreeQ[used, m],
             used[[5]] = m;
             (*operations*)

             used[[5]] = 0;
                  ];
                ];
              used[[4]] = 0;
              ];
            ];
          used[[3]] = 0;
          ];
        ];
      used[[2]] = 0;
      ];
    ];
  used[[1]] = 0
  ];
```

I am not able to find the proper tags, so suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The code has syntax errors... And it's not clear to me what the aim is.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher i hope its clearer now. I want to find all possible sets of the matrix `used` without using all these nested loops, and preferably in a parametric fashion (taking the number of nested loops as an input, say)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following does what you look for.

```
step = {x, ran} \[Function] Select[
    Flatten[Outer[Join, x, Partition[Range @@ ran, 1], 1], 1],
    DuplicateFreeQ
    ];

lb = 3;
ranges = Sort /@ RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {lb, 2}];
Join @@ FoldList[
  step,
  {{}},
  ranges
  ]
```

Maybe you are only interested in (the result of) `Select[Tuples[Range @@@ ranges],DuplicateFreeQ]`. Then

```
Fold[step, {{}}, ranges]
```

provides a much faster alternative (compare for `lb = 10`).

Comment: { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 
  5}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 3}, {1, 2, 5, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 5, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 2, 4, 
  5}, {1, 3, 2, 5, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 2}, {1, 3, 5, 2, 
  4}, {1, 3, 5, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 4, 2, 5, 3}, {1, 4, 3, 2, 
  5}, {1, 4, 3, 5, 2}, {1, 4, 5, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5, 3, 2}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 
  4}, {1, 5, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 5, 3, 2, 4}, {1, 5, 3, 4, 2}, {1, 5, 4, 2, 
  3}, {1, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 1, 3, 5, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3, 
  5}, {2, 1, 4, 5, 3}, {2, 1, 5, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 5, 4, 3}}

Comment: The previous comment is the output i expect when I have `ranges` as {{1, 2}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {2, 5}, {2, 5}}. Your suggestion seems to achieve a different objective. Can you suggest something for this?Also, lb=5

Comment: Then you are in fact interested in `Select[Tuples[Range @@@ ranges], DuplicateFreeQ]` or `Fold[step, {{}}, ranges]`. Both yield the same but for more and longer lists with many duplicates, the latter will be significantly faster.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it!

Comment: Good to hear that!